# Observe a single pulse on an oscilloscope

Tags: oscilloscope, measurement

From my experience oscilloscopes show periodic signals.

If I have a digital circuit and one output changes only once from 0 to 1 and I want to observe this, how can I do it with an oscilloscope? Will it show the transition or will it be lost?

Comment: From my experience, the single shot function of my oscilloscope shows single events.

Comment: The model of scope will determine what is possible.

Comment: How is this not directly covered in the scope's manual, probably exactly where you'd expect to find it?

Comment: @OlinLathrop: easily, my scope does not have this feature, mainly because it's a budget CRO and has no means of storing a waveform for persistent display.  Not all scopes are shiny whiz-bang ones with tassles and sparklies.

Comment: Even the least shiny and whizbang scopes have this feature.  If you are using something unusual like a CRO, you should have said so in the question.  In ancient CROs, this was a high end feature.  Some were storage tubes (Tektronix) or had variable persistance (HP).  On plain CROs you could sometimes get that by using a camera to capture the signle event.

Comment: @OlinLathrop, I didn't write the question.

Comment: @Arash, it is very important that you tell us what scope you have.

Comment: @Wossname: When these days someone posts on superuser.com they can not install firefox, people will start giving the usual troubleshoot steps; when the reason is that firefox does not support Win95 anymore, it is pretty unexpected. The same goes here, if someone says oscilloscope, we think of one of the usual ones produced in the last two decadeds.

Comment: Bought mine new about 11 years ago.

Comment: @Woss: 11 years ago, new low end digital scopes were cheaper than new cathode ray scopes.  And, all the digital scopes had single event capture capability provided somehow.

Comment: GOS-310, well I never said it was a good one.  However it was, and still is a useful tool for a hobbyist on a shoestring budget.

Comment: The only kind of scope that won't show you a single event is a sampling type (which depends on equivalent time sampling). Chances are almost zero your scope is this type (usually used for GHz frequencies).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your experience with oscilloscopes is *very* limited.  Even cheap scopes have *single trigger* mode, although it might have slightly different names between scopes.  This freezes the display after the first trigger event, and does exactly what you are asking for.  Look around in the trigger menu.  Some scopes even have a single trigger button.

If the signal itself only occurs once, then you don't even need a single trigger.  Just a plain old *normal trigger* will do it.  This only updates the display after every trigger.

You need to broaden your horizons by getting out of *auto trigger* mode.  But above all, **READ THE SCOPE MANUAL**.

Comment: Not all cheap scopes have single trigger mode.  Only the shiny whiz-bang ones with tassles and sparklies do.  My Hameg 203 hasn't got one, no matter how often I read the manual.  Not everyone has a DSO.

Comment: @Paul: Yes, this was a high end feature on old analog scopes.  However, "cheap" scopes have been digital for 1-2 decades now.  If you are using something unusual, like a analog scope, then it's your responsibility to say so if you want meaningful feedback.  Put another way, here in 2017, just "oscilloscope", and particularly "cheap oscilloscope" without further qualification implies digital, and all digital scopes have single event capture.  Just like when you say "amplifier" we don't assume its made from tubes unless you say so.  Times move on.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the trigger (the singleshot is a specific type of trigger) function on an oscilloscope to capture a single event signal. The details will differ for each brand, for example here's how to do it on a textronix scope.

http://www.tek.com/manual-topic/capturing-single-shot-signal

Comment: The trigger and the single-shot function are two distinct features of a scope, the trigger is telling the scope when to capture the waveform, in continous capture mode as well as in single-shot mode.

Comment: i've edited the answer to be a bit more specific about the distinction, hope that clarifies things enough

Answer (score 1):

You would set the Trigger to capture a rising edge from the channel your probe is attached to (e.g. see Trigger Menu on a Tek scope). Set the trigger level to about half of the voltage range of the input signal (e.g. 2.5V for a 0 to 5V logic signal).

In the Acquisition menu, you would select Normal mode, then select Single Trigger.

Even the simplest digital oscilloscopes have these features.

Answer (score 1):

If you got a fairly old completely analog scope without a storage display tube, you have no chance. But if you have a digital scope, the trigger and single-shot functions of the scope should help you as mentioned in the other answers.

Answer (score 0):

This is quite possible on any digital oscilloscope using the *single shot* or *single* trigger mode. When the measured voltage exceeds the trigger threshold, the scope triggers one time. Think of a voltage controlled camera shutter button pointing at your scope. When the voltage is high enough (the trigger threshold), the camera takes a photo of the scope's display.